# Opening and closing dialog modal and waiting for response through provider

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

Using React Testing Library to test a dialog provider. I can get it to open, and assert on it appearing — but for some reason I can't get it to close in the test. Do I need to rerender or something?

```
test('await the closing or confirming of the modal', async () => {
  const { debug, getByText, queryByText } = render(
    <DialogProvider>
      <Test />
    </DialogProvider>,
  );
  const openDialogButton = getByText(/click me/i);
  fireEvent.click(openDialogButton);
  await wait(() => getByText(/ok/i));
  fireEvent.click(getByText(/ok/i));
  debug();
});


function Test() {
  const confirm = useConfirmation();
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        confirm({ variant: 'info' });
      }}
    >
      click me
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Apparently, the following seemed to work

```
  await waitForElement(() => getByText(/ok/i));
  fireEvent.click(getByText(/ok/i));
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => queryByText(/ok/i));
  expect(queryByText(/ok/i)).toBeNull();
```

Comment: This solved a similar issue for me in angular testing library-- and it worked when standard `await waitFor` was _not_ working.  I don't understand _why_ exactly, as the docs suggest `waitForElementToBeRemoved` is just a utility that wraps `waitFor`, but, FWIW, if any visitors to this page are having an issue with `await waitFor` this might be a viable solution.

Comment: Thanks. Could not figure out how to close a dialog without this.